# Dynamic SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have a SQL CLR stored procedure `dbo.Parallel_AddSql` that takes a SQL query to execute as a string parameter.

It looks something like this :

```
exec dbo.Parallel_AddSql 'sql1', 
         'insert into test.dbo.table_1 values (1, ''test1'')'
```

I need to pass my SQL query as dynamic SQL statement to `Parallel_AddSql` procedure.

SQL statement that I need to pass is procedure execution statement with parameters i.e

```
Exec dbo.MatchLastName @LastNameFromUser = @LastName,
 @checkbool = @checkbool
```

How do I pass this? As `@lastName` and `@checkbool` will be out of scope if I pass them as such in the string.

I tried using this :

```
set @SQL = 'Exec dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser =' + @firstname + ', 
@checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
exec dbo.Parallel_AddSql 'sql1', @SQL
```

However, I get this error :

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.MatchFirstName'

`dbo.MatchFirstName` is there but `dbo.Parallel_AddSql` is not able to see it at all.

`dbo.Parallel_AddSql` is coming the library code given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29356/Asynchronous-T-SQL-Execution-Without-Service-Broke)

Edit : Unclosed quotation mark error :

```
set @SQL = 'Exec dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser =''' + @firstname
 + ''', @checkbool = ''' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @SQL = 'Exec dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser =''' + @firstname + ''', ...'
```

If you were to call the stored procure in a script, you'd write `Exec dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser = 'John'`, not `Exec dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser = John`, right? Same thing with your dynamic SQL. You have to add in the quotes.

If you want to keep the @FirstName = @FirstName syntax, you'll have to declare and set your variables in the string itself. So,

```
'DECLARE @FirstName Varchar(Max); SET @FirstName = ''John''; EXEC ...'
```

### EDIT

If you look at the example they gave for Parallel_AddSql, they used the fully qualified name of the procedure.

The example from www.codeproject.com:

```
exec ClrLibDb.dbo.Parallel_AddSql 'sql1', 'insert into test.dbo.table_1 values (1, ''test1'')'
```

I think it requires the database to be part of that. So, `YourDbName.dbo.MatchFirstName`. It may be looking at `master` for your stored procedure, which is why it's not finding it.

Comment: Oh, what is that for ?

Comment: I get unclosed quotation mark error with what I wrote, could you please check the update and point why I am getting this error ?

Comment: @Simran You didn't close the the string after your cast statement. Append + '''' to the end of it. That should do it. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if I helped you out. **Helpful tip**: `PRINT` your dynamic string to the console and paste it into a script window and try to run it. That's a really easy way to see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Simran See my edit to the answer. I think that should do it.

Comment: Worked :) Thank you for putting up with me :)Thanks a ton

Comment: @Simran Happy to help. My work project is currently kicking my ass, so it's nice to see someone succeed today. =)